# Count _id occurrences in other collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have a DB structure similar to the following:

Pet owners:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8b8ce70dcbe59d7f1a32"),
    "name" : "bob"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8b8ee70dcbe59d7f1a33"),
    "name" : "mary"
}
```

Pets:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8b4fe70dcbe59d7f1a2a"),
    "name" : "max",
    "owner" : ObjectId("5baa8b8ce70dcbe59d7f1a32")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8b52e70dcbe59d7f1a2b"),
    "name" : "charlie",
    "owner" : ObjectId("5baa8b8ce70dcbe59d7f1a32")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa8b53e70dcbe59d7f1a2c"),
    "name" : "buddy",
    "owner" : ObjectId("5baa8b8ee70dcbe59d7f1a33")
}
```

I need a list of all pet owners and additionally the **number of pets** they own. Our current query looks similar to the following:

```
db.getCollection('owners').aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: 'pets', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'owner', as: 'pets' } },
    { $project: { '_id': 1, name: 1, numPets: { $size: '$pets' } } }
]);
```

This works, however it's quite slow and I'm asking myself if there's a more efficient way to perform the query?

**[update and feedback]** Thanks for the answers. The solutions work, however I can unfortunately see no performance improvement compared to the query given above. Obviously, MongoDB still needs to scan the entire pet collection. My hope was, that the `owner` index (which is present) on the `pets` collection could somehow be exploited for getting just the counts (not needing to touch the pet documents), but this does not seem to be the case.

Are there any other ideas or solutions for a very fast retrieval of the 'pet count' beside explicitly storing the count within the owner documents?

Answer (score 4):

In MongoDB 3.6 you can create custom [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) pipeline and count instead of entire `pets` documents, try:

```
db.owners.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "pets",
            let: { ownerId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$ownerId", "$owner" ] } } },
                { $count: "count" }
            ],
            as: "numPets"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$numPets"
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try tomorrow when back in the office!

Comment: Thanks -- tested this solution, but unfortunately it does not give any (noticeable) performance benefit compared to my original query. I gave some more details in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.owners.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "pets",
    "let": { "ownerId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$$ownerId", "$owner" ] }}},
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "as": "numPets"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "numPets": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$numPets.count", 0] }, 0]}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks -- tested this solution, but unfortunately it does not give any (noticeable) performance benefit compared to my original query. I gave some more details in my original question.

Comment: Do you have index on `owner` field of `pets` collection?

Comment: Yes, there's an index on that field.